# Dart (Flutter) map<String, String>.map has no toList()

Tags: dart

I have a a map structure and I want to make a `DropdownMenuItem<String>` for each entry. What I try to do is to call `.map().toList()` like this

```
var _languages = {
  'en': 'English /',
  'fr': 'French ',
  'nl': 'Dutch',
  'es': 'Spanish'
};

languages.map((key, value) => DropdownMenuItem(
   value: key,
   child: Text(v)
)).toList();
```

(if you are on a Windows, the US/GB is printed as text, if you are on any other platform, it will be flags). The problem now is twofold:

1. The return type 'DropdownMenuItem' isn't a 'MapEntry', as required by the closure's context.
2. The method 'toList' isn't defined for the type 'Map'.

How would I properly create a list out of a map? Is this not possible because a map is not an ordered collection?

Answer (score 5):

[`Map<K, V>.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/map.html) returns *another* `Map`, which isn't what you want.

You instead can create an `Iterable` from the `Map` *first*, and use [`Iterable.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/map.html), which returns another `Iterable`:

```dart
  var menuItems = languages.entries
      .map((mapEntry) =>
          DropdownMenuItem(value: mapEntry.key, child: Text(mapEntry.value)))
      .toList();
```

alternatively:

```dart
  var menuItems = [
    for (var mapEntry in languages.entries)
      DropdownMenuItem(value: mapEntry.key, child: Text(mapEntry.value)),
  ];
```

Answer (score 2):

The `map` method om `Map` is not the same as the `map` method on iterables (such as `List`). Instead of returning an `Iterable`, it returns a `Map`. As such, the inner method needs to return a `MapEntry` so the method can construct a new `Map` object to return. In order to convert this into a list, you need to convert the map itself into a list.

I'm assuming what you want to do is to take the entries in the map and map them to `DropDownButton`, where the language code is the button's value and the language text is the button's text. As such, you want to call `map` on `_langages.entries`, which gives you an `Iterable` of all the keys and values in the map. You can then call `map` on this iterable and it will do what you expect:

```dart
var _languages = {
  'en': 'English /',
  'fr': 'French ',
  'nl': 'Dutch',
  'es': 'Spanish'
};

languages.entries.map((entry) => DropdownMenuItem(
   value: entry.key,
   child: Text(entry.value),
)).toList();
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that `map` is ambigious in Dart. What I want is the original meaning i.e. to transform each item to a new one and not to create a data structure

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a `.map` directly in a scenario like yours as returned type is a `Map<K, V>`, means is a reply of the original but transformed *(if you need to transform it)*. In your scenario you need another kind of **map** that is an `Iterable<dynamic>`.  To have that you have to pass by `.entries` which gives you a  `Iterable<MapEntry<K, V>>` and then call on that `.map` which gives you a `Iterable<T>` where the returned `T` can be even `pizza` :).

here a small piece of code that helps you understand the concept:

```
  final Map<String, String> _languages = {
    'en': 'English /',
    'fr': 'French ',
    'nl': 'Dutch',
    'es': 'Spanish'
  };
 
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      items: _languages.entries
          .map((MapEntry element) => DropdownMenuItem(value: element.key, child: Text(element.value)))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        /**/
      },
    );
  }
```